# Помогите написать регулярное выражение для видео из вк

Tags: python-3.x

Всем привет мне нужно регулярное выражение для python которая подходит под такие ссылки

```
https://vk.com/video-6545375_456241114 
https://vk.com/clip-211443079_456240107
https://m.vk.com/video-6545375_456241114 
https://m.vk.com/clip-211443079_456240107
m.vk.com/video-6545375_456241114 
m.vk.com/clip-211443079_456240107
vk.com/video-6545375_456241114 
vk.com/clip-211443079_456240107
```

она должна определять эти домены и цифры после - их по 9 штук потом _ и опять 9 цифр
Сам не смог реализовать такую регулярку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идентификатор из вашего примера не обязательно состоит из `9 цифр _ 9 цифр`, поэтому итоговое регулярное выражение такое:

```
(https:\/\/|)(m.vk.com|vk.com)\/(video|clip)(-|)[0-9]+_[0-9]+
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! вы мне очень сильно помогли!

Comment: А вы можете дописать регулярное выражение что бы он находил и с - и без него https://m.vk.com/clip211443079_456240107 вот что бы такие тоже находил

Comment: @Andromeda исправил

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!